# Does proving $A ∪ (B ∩ C) ⊆ (A ∪ B) ∩ (A ∪ C)$ prove the distributive law of sets?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Does proving $A ∪ (B ∩ C) ⊆ (A ∪ B) ∩ (A ∪ C)$ prove the distributive law of sets?

I know the proof for A ∪ (B ∩ C) ⊆ (A ∪ B) ∩ (A ∪ C) but not the distributive property of sets but I believe it satisfies the distributive law? Is it or is it not?

Comment: What is the distributive law?

Comment: @Alephnull $A ∪ (B ∩ C) = (A ∪ B) ∩ (A ∪ C)$

Comment: Actually that inequality you are referring to is valid in any lattice, and in particular is valid for sets. It is the reverse inclusion that proves the distributive law.

Answer (score 6):

You are halfway to proving the distributive law. You also need to show the inclusion the other way.